# Publishing end date notification email contains wrong hyperlink

Tags: bug, notifications

I'm using a SharePoint 2013 publishing portal site collection and enabled Item Scheduling for the Pages library.

When I set an end date for an article and check "Notify Page Contact", I receive an email notification from SharePoint at the specified date. But this email contains a wrong link.

The text is as follows: "If you would like the item to remain published past 6/29/2016 1:20:00 PM you will need to extend its publishing [end date](https://sharepointurl/sites/publishingPortalTest/_layouts/15/_layouts/PageSettings.aspx?Region=Scheduling&Page=3&Source=%2Fsites%2FpublishingPortalTest%2FPages%2FTest%2Easpx&CancelSource=%2Fsites%2FpublishingPortalTest%2FPages%2FTest%2Easpx)"

The hyperlink behind "end date" is:  `https://sharepointurl/sites/publishingPortalTest/_layouts/15/_layouts/PageSettings.aspx?Region=Scheduling&Page=3&Source=%2Fsites%2FpublishingPortalTest%2FPages%2FTest%2Easpx&CancelSource=%2Fsites%2FpublishingPortalTest%2FPages%2FTest%2Easpx`

As you can see "/_layouts" is included twice, which obviously leads to an error page when clicking on the link.

Any way to correct that link? Any Cumulative Update (I'm on October 2015) fixing it?

Kind regards,

Tobias

Comment: Same problem here with December 2015 CU.

Comment: Nasty. I'm not sure but you might want to check whether the e-mail is based on a template. There's a small chance that you might be able to fix it by changing the template, although that's obviously just a workaround for the problem itself.  Notification templates are stored in %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\Template\XML

Comment: @Jasper I already checked in there, but as you also mentioned, editing 15-hive files is a workaround and not really suitable for complex server farms with multiple front-ends etc...and also these XML files (I guess it is alerttemplates.xml) are nasty ;-)

Comment: Jep. I think working is MS support and getting a hotfix is the only sustainable solution in this case, seems to be bug.